# JavaScript: Change All Text in Element to Lowercase (not just on UI but in DOM as well)

Tags: javascript, css, case-insensitive

Trying to put together a somewhat hacky way of finding strings that match a word case-insensitively and returning their parent element in the console with my limited JavaScript knowledge.

Say you have this html - a search input box with `id="searchinput"` along with a Submit button with `class="submitButton"`, and then some content below it.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="searchinput">
<button type="submit" class="submitButton">Submit</button>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Charlie sat on the chair.</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>It's a nice day today.</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>charlie went to the store.</p>
</div>
```

And then you have this JS, an event listener that triggers when you click the "Submit" button, which loops through all the div's with `class="wrapper"` looking for any strings within the div that match the `searchValue` you've entered, and console logging each wrapper div that does contain the search term:

```
function submitButtonFunction() {
  searchValue = document.getElementById('searchinput').value;
    // variable that defines the word you type into the search box
  allWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
    // variable that defines all of the elements with the class "wrapper"
  allWrappers.forEach(
      e => { if (e.innerHTML.includes(searchValue)) {
               return console.log(e);
             } else {
               return;
             }
           });
    // loops through each "wrapper" div's innerHTML looking for divs that contain your search word and console logging the div

document.querySelector('.submitButton').addEventListener('click', submitButtonFunction, false)
    // calls the function on click of submit button
```

If you search the word "charlie", it would console log only the third `<div>` above, because it is the only one that exactly matches "charlie" in all lowercase. However, I want the first `<div>` to return too, the one with "Charlie" in uppercase.

I tried something like this, changing the `searchValue` to lowercase, then temporarily changing all the text in the wrapper div's to lowercase with the css `text-tranform: lowercase` property, before looping through the wrapper div's to find the ones that included the `searchValue` string, then removing the `text-transform` property afterward:

```
function submitButtonFunction() {
  searchValue = document.getElementById('searchinput').value.toLowerCase();
    // changes the word you searched to lowercase
  allWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
  allWrappers.forEach(
    e => { e.style.textTransform = "lowercase";
             // changes all the text in the wrapper div to lowercase
          if (e.innerHTML.includes(searchValue)) {
            e.style.removeProperty('text-transform');
             // after finding div's that include the search term, change back to regular case
              return console.log(e);
           } else {
            e.style.removeProperty('text-transform');
              return;
           }
         });
```

However, this only changed how the text *appeared* on the UI (lowercase), while remaining unchanged in the DOM (regular case), as seen in this screenshot below. Note: even when I removed the `.style.removeProperty('text-transform');` line, the console log was still bringing back `e` in regular case. Though my code is slightly different in this image, you get the idea:

[image: Lower Case UI, Regular Case DOM]

Since the DOM remains regular case, searching "charlie" still only brings back the lowercase instances of "charlie" in the console.

Is there a way to actually change the case in the DOM, do a find/compare, and bring back the elements that include a match, then change the case back?

I read other questions that allow you to do a comparison like this:

```
var areEqual = string1.toUpperCase() === string2.toUpperCase();
```

But in order to make that work for me, I would have to put every single word inside of a `<span>` or something in order to loop through all the spans and compare the values, whereas I am looking through a big section of words and trying to find any instances where the search value is included in that text.

I also read about another way you can do a comparison using RegExp, but I haven't learned RegExp yet and am having some trouble understanding the concept.

Of course, if there is an easier way to do this that I'm missing, would love to hear that as well! Keeping in mind I'm a JS newbie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When getting the value of the input, convert it into `toLowerCase`

  `searchValue = document.getElementById("searchinput").value.toLowerCase();`
- It would be great if getting the text inside the `wrapper` using `textContent` so that we can apply `toLowerCase` on it.
  `if (e.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)) {`

**TIP:** why to use return with `console.log` `return console.log(e);` . `console.log` returns `undefined` and better to use `console.log(e)`

```js
const result = console.log(10);
console.log(result);
```

```js
function submitButtonFunction() {
  searchValue = document.getElementById("searchinput").value.toLowerCase();
  // variable that defines the word you type into the search box
  allWrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
  // variable that defines all of the elements with the class "wrapper"
  allWrappers.forEach((e) => {
    if (e.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)) {
      return console.log(e);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
}
// loops through each "wrapper" div's innerHTML looking for divs that contain your search word and console logging the div

document
  .querySelector(".submitButton")
  .addEventListener("click", submitButtonFunction, false);
// calls the function on click of submit button
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="searchinput">
<button type="submit" class="submitButton">Submit</button>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Charlie sat on the chair.</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>It's a nice day today.</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>charlie went to the store.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: omg it worked just using ```e.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue))``` instead of using the css textTransform property like I was trying to do, and your code is much cleaner than mine! Thank you! I will mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help